# C# code in Javascript only runs once!

Tags: c#, javascript, youtube-api

I want to send an email to the users who are watching the video.

So I have a JavaScript code like:

```
var n = 0 ;
//this is the Youtube EventHandler method which will get the new state of Youtube player
function OnStateChange(newState)
{
     // 1 means the player is playing video.
     if(newState == 1)
     {
          <% send(); %>
          document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML =  ++n; 
     }
}
```

And I have a div in the html body

```
<div id="counter"></div>
```

the send() method is a C# function which sends email to somebody.

I thought that each time, when the palyer is playing, there should be an email which will be sent to somebody.
However, it only runs once which is the fisrt time when the page is loading.

After that, I opened the firebug to see what's there. But what I saw is

```
var n = 0 ;
//this is the Youtube EventHandler method which will get the new state of Youtube player
function OnStateChange(newState)
{
     // 1 means the player is playing video.
     if(newState == 1)
     {
          //there is nothing >_<;;;
          document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML =  ++n; 
     }
}
```

So my question is how to make the send() can be run for the each time when the state of player is 1(playing)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using UpdatePanel on Ajax Extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save you the trouble of AJAX you can use old dirty tricks.

First, add hidden form field and hidden iframe to the .aspx code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Send" value="0" />
<iframe name="SendFrame" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

Second, have such JS code instead:

```
if(newState == 1)
{
   document.forms[0].elements["Send"].value = "1";
   document.forms[0].target = "SendFrame";
   document.forms[0].submit();
   document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML =  ++n; 
}
```

And finally in your C# code behind have this in the `Page_Load` method:

```
if (Request.Form["Send"] == "1")
   send();
```

Edit: some explanation first. The above code changes the form **target**, making it submit itself into the hidden frame instead of to the current page which is the default behavior. This cause "AJAX-like" result, without using "real" AJAX. Why? Because data is sent from the browser to the server without the user seeing anything and without page reload. That's what I've done before AJAX existed.

Now, in  case you need to use PostBack in the page, it won't work anymore because the form will still post itself to the frame so the data is "lost". Solution is changing the target back.. as changing it right after submitting the form is likely to cause problems timer is the best way IMO, and revised code is:

```
if(newState == 1)
{
   document.forms[0].elements["Send"].value = "1";
   document.forms[0].target = "SendFrame";
   document.forms[0].submit();
   window.setTimeout(function() { document.forms[0].target = ""; }, 1000);
   document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML =  ++n; 
}
```

This will set the target back to empty after one second, allowing the form to be submitted to the hidden frame in the meanwhile.

Finally you ask "why old trick rather than new"? Because it will work without using any further libraries of code. It's as cross browser as any modern AJAX solutions. Ideal solution to your problem would be telling you to include [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) in your code then the revised code will be only this:

```
if(newState == 1)
{
   $.post(document.forms[0].action, { "Send": "1" });
   document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML =  ++n; 
}
```

And have the same server side code. Personally I don't think you need to include the whole jQuery library just for this one thing, it's like buying 5L water container when you want only one glass - but it's your choice of course. :)

Edit II: Regarding `.ashx` it's the standard way to "listen" for stuff like what we're doing here: instead of posting "Send" to the same page the ideal way is sending it to `.ashx` listener and have the code sending the mail in there. If you want, read [this tutorial](http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/ASP/Generic_Handlers_%28ASHX_Files%29.html) which looks excellent and come back when you're ready for more. ;)

Comment: Thx, I'll try it. see you after 5 mins :)

Comment: In your solution, if the video is playing, then the SendFrame iframe will be submitted, and it will activatied the Page_Load() method, then Page_Load() method will do the c# code. Am I right?

Comment: I found a bug, if I did it in this way. There is a linkbutton on the same web page, initially, after I click it, I will logout and the web page will be redirect to home page, but after use your method, there is nothing happen after clicking the Log out button. So How to solve this trickly problem?

Comment: I got the solution about that :)

Comment: @Franva cheers, glad I could help.. please share the solution, curious to see how you did that. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, ok. Althrough I don't know too much about Javascript and have no idea about iframe, but as you can see my aforementioned analyse about how it works, your code actually replaces the original form for my web page with your SendForm, so there is no code for the LinkedButton, so that's the reason why any component on the page didn't work. Therefore, my solution is to use a variable to store the original form,after that when the state of player is not 1, then I will replace the SendForm with the original one. And I'm not sure whehter it's the best way to do that,but it works for me.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, Do you have any other idea and am I right? because it's my guess. And do you have any idea about what the others said about using AJAX ASHX handler? And you said your code is the old trick, so I would like to know what's the disvantages of the old trick and how to write the code in a new way.   I think I got too many questions :) hopes it will not make you upset.

Comment: @Franva on the contrary, the more the merrier! Answer is too long for comment, see my edit. :-)

Answer (score 3):

C# is run when rendering the page (before page load)

You will have to use an AJAX call to your server, in the OnStateChange function in your JavaScript

Comment: how to do that? I really have no idea about that .

Answer (score 3):

You can not call server side code (C# code) from client side code (JavaScript code).

Not in the way you're trying to do it.

You must trigger some kind of AJAX callback inside the `if (newState === 1)`, and handle the event server side.

Oh, by the way: doing it like this will spam people every time they pause and restart the playback. Not nice. You should implement a check to send the e-mail only once.

Comment: thanks :) but I really have no idea about how to do it with AJAX. Could you please give me a example? Thanks a lot

Comment: As an example you can use [jQuery's AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) to call a C# ASHX handler, which does the e-mail sending thing. Beware of possible abuse of this (people manually calling it to annoy others) so you should also implement some kind of authentication.

Comment: Oh, and obviously do not let the client (the JavaScript code) specify the destination address. It would be very bad. Instead make it pass some sort of encrypted ID you can use to look up the e-mail in your database.

Comment: it sounds good. but is it very hard to write me a example? So is that a difficult way to do it?

Comment: Wouldn't take too long, but I would be writing the C# part by memory since I can't test it right now. On the 'net you can find [many examples](http://www.google.it/search?q=c%23+ashx+tutorial) about them, by the way.

Comment: I made a [quick example](https://gist.github.com/827662), I've left out your business logic as I know nothing about it.

Comment: Hi Kappa, thx to your example, but actually I want to know how to jQuery's AJAX to call a C# ASPX handler. Could you please show it to me? Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

That `<% send(); %>` part isn't magical code whereby the browser can execute server side code.
It is a server side instruction: while rendering the page (including the javascript) this is executed on the server, before the text is sent to the client.

In your case, that email was sent always before the user saw the page and could change that state.

Comment: YES!!! You are totally right, what you said is totally same as what I have seen. So in order to archieve my goal, what should I do?